# Given an example of closed ,bounded subset of $l^p$ $(1\le p< \infty)$ which is not compact

Tags: real-analysis

Given an example of closed ,bounded subset of $l^p$ $(1\le p< \infty)$ which is not compact

can you one give me example

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Simple: the unit ball. For a fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $e_n$ be the sequence that is $0$ at every entry except at entry $n$, in which case it's $1$. So,
\begin{align*}
e_1 &= (1, 0, 0, 0, 0, \ldots) \\
e_2 &= (0, 1, 0, 0, 0, \ldots) \\
e_3 &= (0, 0, 1, 0, 0, \ldots) \\
&\vdots
\end{align*}
Then the sequence of such sequences $(e_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is contained in the unit ball, but has no convergent subsequence. To see this, note that for $n \neq m$, we have
$$\|e_n - e_m\|_p = (|1|^p + |{-1}|^p)^{1/p} = 2^{1/p} \ge 1,$$
and equality holds for $p = \infty$. This same separation must occur for every subsequence, hence there can be no Cauchy subsequence. Therefore, no subsequence will converge, and the unit ball is non-compact.

Comment: Another example with the same proof is the set $\{e_1,e_2,\dots\}$.  I mention this to emphasize how "small" or "sparse" such an example can be.